# NodeJS Mysql async query not being executed when using a while loop to wait for callback

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a function in node js to send a update query where id=x, when I update a table and set multiple values everything works fine but if I update a single column the query and callback is never executed and any other query i make also stops working

**Code**

This is the NodeJs function i call to update

```
    export interface IDBHelperUpdate {
        index: string
        target: string
        data: { [index: string]: string; }
        onSuccess?: (Message: any) => void
        onError?: (Message: any) => void
    }

    static UpdateWithId = (props: IDBHelperUpdate) => {
        var setQuery = "";
        var Arguments = [];        
        for (let key in props.data) {
            setQuery += `, \`${key}\`=?`
            Arguments.push(props.data[key]);
        }

        Arguments.push(props.index);
        setQuery = setQuery.slice(1);
        console.log(`UPDATE ${props.target} SET ${setQuery} WHERE Id=?`)
        console.log(Arguments)
        Database.SimpleQuery({ 
            query: `UPDATE ${props.target} SET ${setQuery} WHERE Id=?`,
            arguments: Arguments,
            onError: (err) => { console.log("Error"); if (props.onError) props.onError(err); },
            onSuccess: (err) => { console.log("Suc"); if (props.onSuccess) props.onSuccess(err); }
        });
    }
```

This is the NodeJs function i use to execute all querys

```
    export interface IQueryProps {
        query: string
        arguments?: string[]
        onSuccess?: (Message: any) => void
        onError?: (Message: any) => void
    }

    static SimpleQuery = (props: IQueryProps) => {
        return new Promise<IQueryResult>((resolve) => {
            pool?.query(props.query, props.arguments, (err, results) => {
                console.log("Callback");
                if (err && props.onError)
                    props.onError(err);
                else if (props.onSuccess)
                    props.onSuccess(results);
            })
        });
    }
```

**Logs**

This are the logs of when i update multiple columns

> UPDATE MainPageBlocks SET  `Title`=?, `Description`=?, `Icon`=?,
> `Tag`=?, `ReadMore`=? WHERE Id=?
>
> [
> 'REAL ESTATE ADVISORY',
> 'Our Real Estate Advisory Services help clients make informed
> decisions to achieve a...',
> 'Assessment',
> 'dwqdwqdqw',
> '%3Cp%3Eqsqs%3C/p%3E',
> '19'
> ]
>
> Callback

This is query is executed succesfully and the callback is executed as we can see by the Callback in the end

This are the logs of when i update one column

> UPDATE MainPageBlocks SET  `Priority`=? WHERE Id=?
>
> [ '0', '19' ]

as you can see the callback is never executed and if i try to do any onther query after this one, in this or any other table, the callback continues not not being executed and the only fix is to restart the nodeJS app, I have no idea of what is causing this and can't find anyone with this problem, if i execute this query in phpmyadmin it works just fine.

I have multiple other queries like `DELETE` `SELECT` and `INSERT` that work just fine with the same query function

This is my table in case you need it

```
CREATE TABLE `MainPageBlocks` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ReadMore` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Icon` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Tag` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Priority` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**UPDATE**

I found out that the problem wasn't caused by the query it self but by the while loop in this code

```
Priority.forEach((Value: string, Index: Number) => {
    var Data = Value.split("_")
    var working = true;
    DatabaseHelper.UpdateWithId({
        target: MainPageBlocksDB.Target,
        index: Data[1],
        data: { Priority: Index.toString() },
        onSuccess: () => { working = false; console.log("S") },
        onError: (err) => { working = false; hasErr = err; console.log("E") }
    })
    while (working) { }
})
```

in this peace of code if I remove `while (working) { }` everything works as expected, but I need to wait for the query to finish before continuing, plus the query is async so I i'm not sure why it affects the query

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answer, I had to come up with an alternative and ended with this

```
var hasErr: any = undefined;
var length = Priority.length;
var complete = 0;

Priority.forEach((Value: string, Index: Number) => {
    var Data = Value.split("_")

    DatabaseHelper.UpdateWithId({
        target: HighlightedPostsDB.Target,
        index: Data[1],
        data: { Priority: Index.toString() },
        onSuccess: () => { 
            complete++; 
            if (complete == length && hasErr == undefined) 
                res.status(200).send(Error.SuccessError()) 
        },
        onError: (err) => { 
            if (hasErr == undefined) {
                hasErr = err;
                res.status(500).send(Error.SQLError())
            }
        }
    })
})
```

So what I ended having to do was every time I received the query callback I had to increase an integer and check if it was equal to the length of queries if yes then send a response if not then just continue, what I wanted was just to send all queries and use a while to see if all completed and then check if there was an error, something like this:

```
var hasErr: any = undefined;
var length = Priority.length;
var complete = 0;

Priority.forEach((Value: string, Index: Number) => {
    var Data = Value.split("_")

    DatabaseHelper.UpdateWithId({
        target: HighlightedPostsDB.Target,
        index: Data[1],
        data: { Priority: Index.toString() },
        onSuccess: () => complete++,
        onError: (err) => { 
            complete++;
            if (hasErr == undefined) {
                hasErr = err;
            }
        }
    })

    while (complete != length) {}

    if (hasErr == undefined) 
        res.status(200).send(Error.SuccessError())
    else 
        res.status(500).send(Error.SQLError(hasErr))
})
```

Since this doesn't really answer why the queries weren't sending a callback I will simply leave this alternative answer here for anyone who has the same problem and if in the future someone explains why I will accept that answer